# I'm having trouble with my code and I'm not sure what's wrong

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm taking a computer programming class in high school right now and one of our assignments has to do with the JOption Pane. We have to allow the user running our program to input the number of miles between them and their uncles house and then we give them the number of feet as an output. It's giving me an error and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Please review my code and find the error if you can(Java programming).

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MilesToFeet 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double feetPerMile = 5280;
        String milesToUncle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of miles to your uncles's house");
        Double.parseDouble(milesToUncle);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The distance to your uncle's house is " + milesToUncle + " miles or " + (feetPerMile*milesToUncle) + " feet.");
    }

}
```

Comment: "It's giving me an error"  -- Would you care to share with us what that error might be?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with `Double.parseDouble(milesToUncle);`.

The method `.parseDouble()` *returns* the `Double` value, it does not modify the `Object` you are currently using.

Use it like this:

```
double miles = Double.parseDouble(milesToUncle);
double result = miles * feetPerMile;
```

You can modify this code to be directly calculated when using `.showMessageDialog()` instead of setting it to the variable `result` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The error you see is that you are trying to multiply a `double` value with a `String` value, which doesn't make sense.

Try this – it saves the output of `Double.parseDouble(milesToUncleInput)` into a new variable, and then uses that variable to do `feetPerMile * milesToUncle`.

```
double feetPerMile = 5280;
String milesToUncleInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number of miles to your uncles's house");
double milesToUncle = Double.parseDouble(milesToUncleInput);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The distance to your uncle's house is " + milesToUncleInput + " miles or " + (feetPerMile * milesToUncle) + " feet.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `milesToUncle` is an Object of type String, so you cannot multiply it with `feetPerMile`

That's the error I can see at first sight.